# Add file to SharePoint list item column using JavaScript

Tags: list, javascript, attachments, powerapp, add-item

I created a custom form using PowerApps. In this form one can also add attachments.
The attachment column also shows up when I go to the list, but when I go to the list settings, there's no "Anlagen" column.

[image]

What I want to achieve is that a user should be able to add files to that list item via JavaScript.
I used this in JavaScript, but it says that it [can't find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92SrI.jpg) the "Anlagen" column. I can't create that column because the type "attachments" [does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXzDw.jpg):

```
onUploadFile() {
    var siteUrl = 'https://thesite.sharepoint.com/sites/Playercard/';

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Player');
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(52);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.selectedFile); // appending file

    oListItem.set_item('Anlagen', formData);

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
},
onQuerySucceeded: function(){
    console.log("Succeeded!")
},

onQueryFailed: function(sender, args){
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
},
```

How can I add attachments to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSj6O.jpg) using JavaScript or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We **can't** create a custom attachment type column in SharePoint, it is the default behavior, we have to attach the attachment to the existing out of the box attachment column.

You can use the below javascript code to attach the attachment :

```
    <html>  
  <head>  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
        var fileInput;  
        $(document).ready(function()   
        {  
            fileInput = $("#getFile");  
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', registerClick);  
        });  

        function registerClick()   
        {  
            //Register File Upload Click Event  
            $("#addFileButton").click(readFile);  
        }  
        var arrayBuffer;  

        function readFile()   
        {  
            //Get File Input Control and read th file name  
            var element = document.getElementById("getFile");  
            var file = element.files[0];  
            var parts = element.value.split("\\");  
            var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];  
            //Read File contents using file reader  
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function(e) {  
                uploadFile(e.target.result, fileName);  
            }  
            reader.onerror = function(e)   
            {  
                alert(e.target.error);  
            }  
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);  
        }  
        var attachmentFiles, clientContext, createInfo;  

        function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName)   
        {  
            //Get Client Context and Web object.  
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();  
            var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();  

            //Get list and Attachment folder where the attachment of a particular list item is stored.  
            var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('NewList');  
            var attachmentFolder = oWeb.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/NewList/Attachments/1');  

            //Convert the file contents into base64 data  
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
            var i, length, out = '';  
            for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1) {  
                out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
            }  
            var base64 = btoa(out);  
            //Create FileCreationInformation object using the read file data  
            createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
            createInfo.set_content(base64);  
            createInfo.set_url(fileName);  

            //Add the file to the list item  
            attachmentFiles = attachmentFolder.get_files().add(createInfo);  

            //Load client context and execute the batch  
            clientContext.load(oList);  
            clientContext.load(attachmentFiles);  
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
        }  

        function QuerySuccess()   
        {  
            console.log("Attachment added successfuly ");  
        }  

        function QueryFailure(sender, args)   
        {  
            console.log('Request failed with error message - ' + args.get_message() + ' . Stack Trace - ' + args.get_stackTrace());  
        }  
    </script>  
</head>  

<body>  
    <input id="getFile" type="file" /><br />  
    <input id="addFileButton" type="button" value="Upload" />  
</body>  
<html>
```

Reference URL :

[Upload File To List Item In Office 365 As An Attachment Using JavaScript Object Model](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-file-to-listitem-in-office-365-as-an-attachment-using-javascript-object-m/)

As an alternate using the REST API, we can attach the attachment to the SharePoint list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var ID = 1;
 var listname = "UploadTEST";

 $("#my-attachments").change(function() {

  var file = $(this)[0].files[0];

  var getFileBuffer = function(file) {

   var deferred = $.Deferred();
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(e) {
    deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
   }

   reader.onerror = function(e) {
    deferred.reject(e.target.error);
   }

   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

   return deferred.promise();
  };

  getFileBuffer(file).then(function(buffer) {

   $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
     "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items(" + ID + ")/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
    method: 'POST',
    data: buffer,
    processData: false,
    headers: {
     "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
     "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
     "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value,
     "content-length": buffer.byteLength
    }
   });

  });

 });
});
```

For details you may refer to the below article:

[Uploading Attachments to SharePoint Lists Using REST](https://sympmarc.com/2016/04/20/uploading-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists-using-rest/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Habibur! The upload works now, but I can't open list elements in View/Edit mode. Even elements that don't have any attachments. Do you know what the issue might be?

Comment: Glad to know that it works.  For your second issue why the list item does not open, not exactly sure why, but definitely will update if anything I find. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fixed it by restoring an older version of the form in PowerApps

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use the above code to upload the files in list using HTML form, but unfortunately i got an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined". Can any please help me to solve the issue